# RDP or VNC to Loki

Tags: release-loki, rdp, vnc

Has anyone successfully configured Elementary OS Loki for RDP or VNC?  I really like Elementary OS and would like to use it for my headless development environment and keep the desktop Pantheon Desktop.

I know that I can install XFCE or Mate and VNC to it, but I'd like to use Pantheon if it is possible. I've come across various blogs, etc. that successfully remote desktop to Unity and they didn't work for me with Pantheon.  I thought maybe someone else has had some success, so thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

For my headless elementary machines, I tend to set up the VNC server via LightDM. It requires the `tigervnc` server to be installed. You can configure it as follows:

Create a `vncpasswd` file:

```
sudo vncpasswd /etc/vncpasswd
```

Configure `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with the following contents:

```
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=Xvnc -rfbauth /etc/vncpasswd
port=5900
listen-address=localhost
width=1024
height=768
depth=24
```

Then restart the machine or restart lightdm, which will kill your session. VNC should then be listening on the port specified in the config file and you will be presented with the elementary greeter when you connect. Logging into the machine locally will log you out of your VNC session and vice versa.